# Using conditional logic on timestamp

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm writing a script that will compare times between 2 servers, and compare the time difference. The returned timestamp is in the format below:

```
-00:00:01.9989999
-01:00:02 
-00:00:00.9989999
```

I need to create a condition where the action would be triggered, only if the difference is greater then 3 minutes. How should I format this?

Comment: Unless you can guarantee both of the time stamps being compared are on the same day, you're going to need a date component to go along with the time stamps to get accurate results.

Comment: `([timespan]'-00:00:00.9989999').Duration() -gt (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 3)`

Comment: @mjolinor I'm converting the datetime objects to UTC first, and all are within the same physical boundary (US), so I would be very shocked if there was a difference in date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @PetSerAl suggested, cast the times to timespans, get the `Duration()` of their difference (the absolute value of the difference, if you will), and compare it to a timespan of 3 minutes:

```psh
$t1 = [timespan]'-00:00:01.9989999'
$t2 = [timespan]'-00:00:00.9989999'

$delta = ($t1 - $t2).Duration()

if ($delta -gt [timespan]'00:03:00') {
  # do stuff
}
```